NextJS redirect in server action
I have a fairly simple login page, with a server side action. After the login has been completed, and a session created, I simply want to redirect the user to /app.
However none of that seems to be working. When looking at the network requests, I can indeed see a POST request to auth/login, with a 303 response. The response is a bit vague, but I can see that there's a 404 page not found.
Looking at the server logs, I can see the login action being completed, as well as the logs from the /app layout. Yet it just reloads the login page.
3:I["(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js",["app-pages-internals","static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js"],""]
4:I["(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js",["app-pages-internals","static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js"],""]
1:D{"name":"","env":"Server"}
2:D{"name":"AppPage","env":"Server"}
5:D{"name":"AppRootLayout","env":"Server"}
6:D{"name":"NotFound","env":"Server"}
6:[["$","title",null,{"children":"404: This page could not be found."}],["$","div",null,{"style":{"fontFamily":"system-ui,\"Segoe UI\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,\"Apple Color Emoji\",\"Segoe UI Emoji\"","height":"100vh","textAlign":"center","display":"flex","flexDirection":"column","alignItems":"center","justifyContent":"center"},"children":["$","div",null,{"children":[["$","style",null,{"dangerouslySetInnerHTML":{"__html":"body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}"}}],["$","h1",null,{"className":"next-error-h1","style":{"display":"inline-block","margin":"0 20px 0 0","padding":"0 23px 0 0","fontSize":24,"fontWeight":500,"verticalAlign":"top","lineHeight":"49px"},"children":"404"}],["$","div",null,{"style":{"display":"inline-block"},"children":["$","h2",null,{"style":{"fontSize":14,"fontWeight":400,"lineHeight":"49px","margin":0},"children":"This page could not be found."}]}]]}]}]]
7:D{"name":"","env":"Server"}
0:["development",[[["",{"children":["(app)",{"children":["app",{"children":["__PAGE__",{}]}]},"$undefined","$undefined",true]}],["",{"children":["(app)",{"children":["app",{"children":["__PAGE__",{},[["$L1","$L2"],null],null]},["$","$L3",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children","(app)","children","app","children"],"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","errorScripts":"$undefined","template":["$","$L4",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","templateScripts":"$undefined","notFound":"$undefined","notFoundStyles":"$undefined","styles":null}],null]},["$L5",null],null]},["$","$L3",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children"],"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","errorScripts":"$undefined","template":["$","$L4",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","templateScripts":"$undefined","notFound":"$6","notFoundStyles":[],"styles":[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/app/(app)/layout.css?v=1717519684402","precedence":"next_static/css/app/(app)/layout.css","crossOrigin":"$undefined"}]]}],null],[null,"$L7"]]]]
2:["$","div",null,{"children":"test"}]
7:[["$","meta","0",{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],["$","meta","1",{"charSet":"utf-8"}],["$","title","2",{"children":"Pro Writing Buddy"}],["$","link","3",{"rel":"icon","href":"/favicon.ico","type":"image/x-icon","sizes":"16x16"}]]
1:null
8:I["(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/(app)/components/Navigation.tsx",["app/(app)/layout","static/chunks/app/(app)/layout.js"],"default"]
9:D{"name":"Usage","env":"Server"}
9:["$","div",null,{"className":"p-5 rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-br from-violet-500 to-purple-500 text-white","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"font-semibold","children":"Usage"}],["$","div",null,{"className":"my-2","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"w-full h-2 rounded-lg bg-white overflow-hidden","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"bg-slate-800 h-full","style":{"width":"50%"}}]}]}],["$","div",null,{"children":"5,000 / 10,000 credits used"}],["$","div",null,{"className":"mt-5 bg-white rounded-md text-gray-900 text-center py-3 px-5","children":"Upgrade now"}]]}]
a:D{"name":"NotFound","env":"Server"}
b:{"fontFamily":"system-ui,\"Segoe UI\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,\"Apple Color Emoji\",\"Segoe UI Emoji\"","height":"100vh","textAlign":"center","display":"flex","flexDirection":"column","alignItems":"center","justifyContent":"center"}
c:{"display":"inline-block","margin":"0 20px 0 0","padding":"0 23px 0 0","fontSize":24,"fontWeight":500,"verticalAlign":"top","lineHeight":"49px"}
d:{"display":"inline-block"}
e:{"fontSize":14,"fontWeight":400,"lineHeight":"49px","margin":0}
a:[["$","title",null,{"children":"404: This page could not be found."}],["$","div",null,{"style":"$b","children":["$","div",null,{"children":[["$","style",null,{"dangerouslySetInnerHTML":{"__html":"body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}"}}],["$","h1",null,{"className":"next-error-h1","style":"$c","children":"404"}],["$","div",null,{"style":"$d","children":["$","h2",null,{"style":"$e","children":"This page could not be found."}]}]]}]}]]
5:["$","html",null,{"lang":"en","children":["$","body",null,{"className":"w-screen h-screen overflow-hidden","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"flex h-full","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"w-3/12 border-r border-gray-300","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"flex flex-col h-full","children":[["$","nav",null,{"className":"p-5","children":["$","$L8",null,{}]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"mt-auto p-5","children":"$9"}]]}]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"w-9/12 p-10","children":["$","$L3",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children","(app)","children"],"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","errorScripts":"$undefined","template":["$","$L4",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","templateScripts":"$undefined","notFound":"$a","notFoundStyles":[],"styles":null}]}]]}]}]}]

/app/pages/auth/login.tsx
export default function LoginPage() {
    const { pending } = useFormStatus();
    const [state, formAction] = useFormState<{ errors: {[key: string]: string[]} }, FormData>(login, initialState);

    return (
        <form action={formAction}>
            ....
        </form>
    )
}

/app/actions/login.ts
export const login = async (prevState: any, formData: FormData): Promise<any> => {
    ... login logic

    redirect(`/app`, RedirectType.push);
}


make sure you are using redirect imported from the next/navigation and if you are wrappin the redirect inside the try catch
try{
} catch (error)
{}

redirect(`/app`, RedirectType.push);

like  this

I'm already using the import from import { RedirectType, redirect } from "next/navigation"; and it's not wrapped inside a try/catch. Even when my server action is just an empty action with only a redirect, it's not doing anything.

'use client'
 
import { useFormState } from 'react-dom'
import { createUser } from '@/app/actions'
 
const initialState = {
  message: '',
}
 
export function Signup() {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(createUser, initialState)
 
  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
 
   
      <button>Sign up</button>
    </form>
  )
}


add use client directive on the top of the file

thiw work for me. thanks. i use next 15.

Try to use the absolute path in the redirect function.
Example:
redirect('http://localhost:3000/app')

